Polarity Markings in Relay Datasheets
I'm looking at finding LCSC alternatives for a relay that I'm currently sourcing from DigiKey. The part I'm currently using (with no issues) is the AGQ200S03Z.
My issue is the polarity markings for the new parts I've found compared to the datasheet of the AGQ200S03Z, as I messed this up in the first revision of the board and don't want to mess it up again when finding an alternative.
I've found two alternatives on LCSC. FTR-B3GA003Z-B10 and G6K-2F-Y-TR DC3. My question is - which relay will work with my current layout / schematic? The polarity markings are confusing. With my current layout, when I apply 3V across 1 (+) and 8 (-) the relay throws over from pin 2 to pin 4.
My schematic of it working looks like this (with pin 1 being +ve, and 8 being -ve to energize):

In the datasheet it shows the following:

Originally I had pins 8 and 1 wired backwards in my revision 1, because the datasheet says this was the de-energized state - I now know they were referring only to the pins 2 to 7 (augh).
FTR-B3GA003Z-B10:

This one seems to suggest that pin 1 is positive in the in the non-operating state, and pin 8 is positive in the operating state. I take this as the opposite of what I have in my schematic, but there non-operating state has no parenthesis which actually matches my original part's datasheet.
G6K-2F-Y-TR DC3:

This matches my current part's datasheet directly but the polarity, to me, seems to suggest connections between pins 7 and 6, and 2 and 3, when pin 1 is +ve, and pin 8 is -ve.
Your help is much appreciated!  Thanks!

For completeness sake (incase someone else sees this in the future):  I went with the G6K-2F-Y-TR DC3, and it is confirmed working.  The datasheet shows the normally closed state, and pins 1 and 8 show how voltage should be applied to move to the normally open state. (i.e. pin 3 connects to pin 4 when pin 1 is positive and pin 8 is negative).

My expectation is that they are all the same. There is no percentage in a manufacturer making theirs incompatible. 1 is positive relative to 8 when the relay is energized. Contacts are shown in the de-energized (or 'reset', for latching) state.
Here is another datasheet for the same FTR-B3 relay that shows the polarity all in parenthesis and in the expected direction (by my reading). Here is a datasheet in the original Japanese language. Up to you how much you want to do to verify that if you choose Fujitsu. Looks to me like a simple mistake in the footnote on page 7.

Unrelated, but it is a bit nasty that they mix top view (SMT versions) with bottom view (THT versions) on the same datasheet.

Great info thanks!  The Japanese datasheet is really less confusing - even as an English speaker. Just as you said - my suspicion was that the contacts are shown in de-energized state, and that the polarity marks are to show how the voltage needs to be applied to get it into an energized state.  Thank you for your interpretation. Yes, nasty-ness all around in these datasheets for something seemingly simple.


This one seems to suggest that pin 1 is positive in the in the
non-operating state, and pin 8 is positive in the operating state. I
take this as the opposite of what I have in my schematic, but there
non-operating state has no parenthesis which actually matches my
original part's datasheet.

The data sheet covers a regular type and a latching version of the relay hence, you need to buy the right one (non-latching) and, the confusion you have is because they are offering information about both relays on the same diagram.

Please also note this shown below the pin wiring image: -


This matches my current part's datasheet directly but the polarity, to me, seems to suggest connections between pins 7 and 6, and 2 and 3, when pin 1 is +ve, and pin 8 is -ve.

No, the diagram shows the normally closed inactive state (just the same as your current relay).

Hi Andy.  Thanks for your reply.  I thought I'd update this.  I went with the G6K-2F-Y-TR DC3 and, indeed, when I apply 3V3 to pin 1 and GND to pin 8, pin 2 gets switched to pin 4.
